# Something happened to my cursor in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I clicked a keyboard shortcut by wrong that made my cursor turn into a rectangular block instead of a line, as in the picture.

I tried to undo but it undoes the code instead.

The character flashes then whenever I type something the character is changed to what I typed then It goes to the next character.

Please help.

EDIT 2023:
6 years later there are still people that find this helpful. You guys should know something. It is called a caret and not a cursor.

[image: the character flashes then whenever I type something the character is changed to what I typed then It goes to the next character. Please help.]

Comment: seems like you're in `Overwrite` mode. Try pressing the `Insert` key.

Comment: I remember this happening to me in college and I was like WTF is this! I soon learned what that was all about and how useful it can be. @ItaiBar-Haim is correct. You toggle between this mode using the `Insert` key. What it does is replaces the selected character with the typed character.

Comment: Thanks guys. But there is a question why everybody put his answer in the comment instead of putting it as an answer!!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Seems like you're in "Overwrite" mode. Try pressing the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key.

Thanks to the @ItaiBar-Haim in the comment.

Answer (score 11):

This error is mostly caused by the plugin vim editor installed in android studio. try to disable it, all shall get back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

If in your keyboard there is no insert button press space and numberpad zero(0).

Answer (score 1):

on Windows devices, on the keyboard simply press key the **Insert**  and you'll be returned to the original!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just pressed button "Insert" on top of keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `insert` button wasn't the solution because the carets got inverted (i.e. pressing insert would change the caret back to a line, but then the caret would be in "overwrite" mode). In that case, ensure that the `Use block caret` setting is disabled.

[image: Screenshot showing 'Use block caret' toggle in settings.]